# Is it wise to use with with statements in generators?

Tags: python, generator, with-statement, contextmanager

Consider the following Python code:

```
def values():
    with somecontext():
        yield 1
        yield 2
for v in values():
    print(v)
    break
```

In this case, does Python guarantee that the generator is properly closed and, thus, that the context is exited?

I realize that it, in practice, is going to be the case in CPython due to reference counting and eager destruction of the generator, but does Python guarantee this behavior? I do notice that it does indeed not work in Jython, so should that be considered a bug or allowable behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a `with` statement in a generator without issue. Python will handle the context correctly, because the generator will be closed when garbage collected.

In the generator a `GeneratorExit` exception is raised when the generator is garbage collected, because it'll be closed at that time:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def somecontext():
...     print 'Entering'
...     try:
...         yield None
...     finally:
...         print 'Exiting'
... 
>>> def values():
...     with somecontext():
...         yield 1
...         yield 2
... 
>>> next(values())
Entering
Exiting
1
```

This is part of [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), where closing a generator raises the exception. Reaping a generator that has no references left should always close that generator, if Jython is not closing the generator I'd consider that a bug.

See points 4 and 5 of the Specification Summary:

> 4. Add a `close()` method for generator-iterators, which raises `GeneratorExit` at the point where the generator was paused.  If
>        the generator then raises `StopIteration` (by exiting normally, or
>        due to already being closed) or `GeneratorExit` (by not catching
>        the exception), `close()` returns to its caller.  If the generator
>        yields a value, a `RuntimeError` is raised.  If the generator
>        raises any other exception, it is propagated to the caller.
>        `close()` does nothing if the generator has already exited due to
>        an exception or normal exit.
> 5. Add support to ensure that `close()` is called when a generator
>         iterator is garbage-collected.

The only caveat then is that in Jython, IronPython and PyPy the garbage collector is not guaranteed to be run before exiting the interpreter. If this is important to your application you can explicitly close the generator:

```
gen = values()
next(gen)
gen.close()
```

or trigger garbage collection explicitly.

Comment: I cannot obviously find any statement in the langdoc that guarantees this behavior. As I wrote in the question, I realize that it's going to be the case in common practice, but is it safe to rely on? Should I report the lack of this functionality as a bug to the Jython people?

Comment: @Dolda2000: I am building you a testcase to show; it does sound like Jython has a bug in that respect.

Comment: I do already have a testcase that shows it to be working on CPython, but what I'm really asking is whether it should be considered well-defined or merely an accident of CPython implementation. I'm asking because I'm building a system where I would like to truly rely on the behavior and where the correctness of it is fairly important.

Comment: @Dolda2000: added a PEP reference for you.

Comment: '*Add support to ensure that close() is called when a generator iterator is garbage-collected*' -- That's fine and all, but I don't think the language specification guarantees that garbage-collection happens eagerly.

Comment: I think I agree with Dolda2000 here -- PyPy doesn't print Exiting either, even on (close: wrong word) exit.  I have to manually call `gc.collect()` before I see it.

Comment: @DSM: That's even more a bug then; `gen = values()`, `next(gen)` then `gen.close()` should *definitely* trigger the `GeneratorExit` being raised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: poor choice of words on my part, I should have said "exit".

Comment: @DSM: but you *do* see it when calling `gc.collect()`; it is garbage collection that closes the generator there. Just like in CPython, but not as instantaneous.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Indeed, but leaving a potentially sensitive context active until the next GC happens is not what I'd normally consider "safe". :) It would be very poor indeed to, for instance, leave a mutex lock like that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: maybe I'm misreading the storyline here, then.  I thought we were wondering if Python-the-language guaranteed we'd see Exiting, and the evidence you've mustered shows "we're promised to see it on garbage collection, which may never happen".

Comment: @DSM: Updated slightly; yes, it is garbage collection that should do this.

Comment: @Dolda2000: then it is up to you to ensure that the generator is closed earlier. :-)

Comment: Sure, but given all the caveats, I would argue that the answer to the question should be "No" rather than "Yes". :)

Answer (score 0):

If your emphasis is on safety, you can always wrap the generator in a `contextlib.closing` - this seems like the most straightforward solution:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(gen_values()) as values:
    for value in values:
        ...
```

In fact, if it were me I'd write the function as

```
def gen_values():
    def inner():
        ...

    return closing(inner())
```

ensuring that any user has to put this in a `with` to use it.

Comment: Well, yes; thanks for your answer, but I was already aware that I can use an explicit context if I want to be sure. The question was mainly about whether I actually needed that. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000 Sure, but I feel Martijn answered that fine. I was just giving a nicer way to deal with it.