# Python `with` statement and file reading generator

Tags: python, generator, with-statement

I have following code to perform circular reading of ordinary text file:

```
def file_reader(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            for line in f:
                yield line.strip()
            f.seek(0)
```

I am wondering when file will be closed if user press `Ctrl+C` somewhere during program executes?

Comment: Related: [Is it wise to use with with statements in generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29040534)

Answer (score 0):

The file *may not be closed by Python*. It'll be closed because the OS will close all open file handles as a process exits.

CPython can and does, during the shutdown process, clean up generators, but the process is not *guaranteed*, but a best-effort attempt will be made to clear all references in any imported module, causing reference counts drop to 0.

The generator object will *probably* be cleared and have their `__del__` method called, which will in turn call `generator.close()`, which will throw a `GeneratorExit` exception for the `yield` line, which will cause the generator to exit and the `with` statement to close the file object.